# Backbone js, showing undefined in console

Tags: backbone.js

Im writing a backbone application where the User model has to be fetched with the data of the logged in user. In my template i need to display user information(Username,  Name etc).  After compiling template error message is been logged in console "Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined". The Ajax request is also completed successfully. What might be the problem?

Im linking my js files.

[Link to js files](https://mega.co.nz/#!N8YGjQIR!fkwQEWQqnFEBXQE-SIEAtS6NXy45qKOaIppyAARhDNA)

Comment: i dont see a collection.fetch in your userView.js

Comment: Could you post the JS file on JSFiddle/JSBin?

Comment: i dont use collection for this,  is it necessary to use collection for every view?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/techhahn/4946747
created a gist

Answer (score 0):

Even though your AJAX request succeeds, it most likely hasn't succeeded yet by the time you execute the underscore template. You call `render` immediately after `fetch`, which is an asynchronous operation. When this line of code executes, `model.toJSON()` call most likely returns an empty object.

You should move the `fetch` call to your view's `initialize` function like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.model.fetch({success:this.render});
}
```

This will postpone the rendering until the model is successfully fetched.